# How is it advantageous for fuel management to detect negative mass air flow?

Tags: engine-theory, maf

Here is the flow-voltage mapping for the Bosch sensor utilized by my E39 M5.

I find it curious that readings below 0.9 V correspond to negative flows.

[image: BMW E39 M5 MAF map]

### Questions

- Is it possible that air can flow the other way (maybe through some sort of pressure wave that results from sudden throttle plate closure)?
- Given that this is a hot-film MAF sensor (essentially a hot-wire anemometer), how does it detect change in flow direction?
- Why should fuel management care about negative mass air flow? Assuming sudden throttle plate closure results in back flow, I would imagine that the throttle position sensor can be used to detect this scenario as well.

Comment: Have you considered the effect of reversion?

Comment: Reversion is not the norm. I would be surprised if 20-year old fuel management can detect reversion and make adjustments accordingly.

Comment: Looking at the chart, the negative flow doesn't make up a large amount of it. To me, that means it won't happen very often. If there is reversion and the ECU can detect for it, this would tell the injectors not to fire. This would hopefully prevent fuel from going place it shouldn't and also prevent the engine from possibly running in reverse.

Comment: Reversion is common on turbo cars when snapping the throttle shut under boost as the compressed air must now go somewhere. Even with a BOV the air pressure will equalise eventually, this means it must go back out the intake and will be "reverse" flow.

Answer (score 10):

There is no such thing as detectable "reversion" airflow to a MAF.  Especially on a non turbocharged car.  The MAF has no clue about the direction of flow, only how much energy it takes to keep the wire or film heated.

I doubt that the "negative" aspect of your graph is ever seen.  Even at idle, you shoud see 2-5 g/s.  I wonder why the graph is kg/h... that seems like ugly units for a MAF that needs to respond instantly (hopefully). Potatos, Apples. Too lazy to convert. My pedantry, not yours.

Simply put, if your car is at idle, it must be using air.  Snap closure of a throttle butterfly at speed might cause some backflow, but again a MAF has no idea about the direction.  So this is meaningless.  Without knowing the BMW E39 Engine Control Unit (ECU) maps, I am certain 0% Throttle Position Sensor (TPS) is a cell (or cells) on the ECU map.  Cells which ignore all MAF information, <1.7v or not.  Your IDC (injector duty cycle) should go to zero (no fuel injection).  No air, no fuel.

The graph implies a scaling, but you should not assume that every point on the graph is obtainable in running conditions.

And everything I just typed is meaningless without tacit understanding of what the ECU does with this information.  So to answer "why should fuel management care" I would say it probably doesn't.  I would also say (again) that there is no such thing... google how hot film or hot wire works... there is no element of any type MAF (wire/film) that I am familiar with that senses direction of airflow.

And actually, this is the crux of the problem.  MAFs are awesome, but limited.  In a turbo application, even more so.  The ultimate goal is to find the proper Air Fuel Ratio.  But even that is wrong...  we imagine a utopian sensor that would count free oxygen molecules (O2), not NOx or water, that we can use for go-fast combustion.  It should be termed Oxygen/Fuel Ratio.(Even "fuel" isn't right; are we talking 91 or 93 pump, E85 (flexfuel/alchol)?? Gotta count every oxygen and every carbon)  On a nice fast ride (actually anything), such a sensor doesn't exist--especially at 300-500 cfm.  So whatever MAF technology the Bavarians in Munich decided to use, it's probably top-notch.  I don't know where the graph came from, but "negative" airflow areas are not plausible.  Show me a below 1.7v reading on your working MAF on your running E39 and I'll eat my hat.  Yours too.

Not something to be concerned about.

---

**On edit:   Forget every single thing you just read.  I am totally, utterly, completely wrong.**

> Eine elektronische Hybridschaltung wertet diese Messdaten aus und ermöglicht     so die genaue Erfassung der durchströmten Luftmenge **einschließlich der Strömungsrichtung.** ...  *A hybrid electronic circuit evaluates the measurement data and enables the accurate detection of the air volume, **including the direction of flow.***

This is from [Bosch MAF HFM5](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=de&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Frb-aa.bosch.com%2Fboaasocs%2F%3Bjsessionid%3D841BDF86E827B730FEFEB176C201459B.sundoro2%3Fccat_id%3D72&anno=2)

If you look at the schematic you can see that the output signal operational amplifier is biased by *multiple* temperature-sensing resistors, in different places on the film.  So it knows which part of the film cools first, in a way.  It can sense the direction of slightly reversed airflow.

**I've got hat sauce to pick out.**   As far as the "why", I can only speculate (*gee, great track record so far Steve*) that this MAF behavior might be useful in a turbocharged application.  After eating much crow, I still stand by my assertion that there will be little to no reversion airflow on a Normally Aspirated engine.

On edit edit:  A better [speculation] might be now you have capability for a closed loop electronic Idle Air Controller, able to deal with a wide range of operating conditions, yielding potentially lower idle emissions, even on an Open Loop cold start--which has traditionally been a very difficult task to do well.

Comment: My questions are more curiosity than concern. It would be so easy for Bosch to blank out those fields as zeros, yet they chose to assign negative values. Also, 0-5 V is the usable range for these sensors, so I find it puzzling that they should go through the trouble to assign negative values to the sensor's mapping. The curve in the question is what BMW programmed into the M5 ECU, so there's clearly a use for those numbers.

Comment: Awesome answer... except for the use of mystery abbreviations. Okay to use them, but best practice is to ALWAYS define them when first used.  ECU, MAF, E85, IDC, AFR.  Anything else is just poor communication.

Comment: Now I'm curious as well.  Makes no sense.  Why waste precious MAF sensor sweep range on a fairytale condition?  My only guess is that is a base map, and additional information will drive those numbers positive.  For instance (just guessing), maybe a -40 to +250F IAT is buried in the MAF as well, and your graph depicts "corrected" MAF values at a ludicrous 250F air temperature.  More reasonable and realistic temperatures add to the cell values on your map as cooler air predicts denser charge.  I dunno.  Those numbers MUST be corrected somehow.  Any airflow is "positive" airflow to a MAF.

Comment: @zipit.  Noted and edited.  My tone was for the OP, but I was remiss in remembering there's potentially a larger audience.  thnx

Comment: I have some info that should shed some light on the matter. Stay tuned

Comment: I am no longer curious.  Apologies for leading astray.

Comment: @Zaid  I was referring to my comment, not yours-gladly await your further information.  What material is the hat you wear??

Comment: The HFM5 datasheet was what I wanted to share. Good job with the edit. You're fortunate that I'm not into hats, though I'm wondering if you should make one out of rice paper to keep your word :D

Comment: Rude to type with my mouth full, but all that and the "why" question still isn't answered conclusively.  But a virtual IAC made from the MAF and the Electronic Throttle Motor makes sense?

Comment: If virtual idle air control is possible, there's probably a good reason why they have a real IAC valve...

Comment: So I'm gonna call in some favors.  Despite my rusty German.  I worked for both BMW and Bosch.  Now this is bucket-list for me.  There must be a good explanation.  And I must know.  Why does my breath smell of hats??

Comment: At some point, you should remove the incorrect information so that the actual answer is easier to read.

Comment: @Ellesedil ... I will.  Just have to preserve the valid information without removing any well-deserved shame.  Bottom line the heart of the OP's original question has not been answered.

Comment: Maybe you could put the edit on top of the original content, thereby preserving your "well-deserved shame" (your quote, not mine :))

Comment: There are actually two conditions where reversion exists and cause problems. Turbo cars with no BOV, snap the throttle shut and a lot of compressed air now goes out the intake (making that tututu sound), this can start happening before the throttle is completely shut meaning a lot of metered air never enters the engine. Also on large cammed cars you can get massive fluctuations at idle that can go periodically in reverse.