# Why do modern PCMs prefer MAP over MAF

Tags: maf, tuning, electronic-control-module, manifold-absolute-pressure-sensor

Why do modern PCMs prefer to use pressure sensors to estimate the air charge going into an engine instead of air flow meters. Eg they typically use a MAP sensor and complex software to estimate air charge based on current cam positions when a simple MAF would avoid the need for any software to estimate this.

With infinitely variable exhaust and intake cams these airflow models are becoming extremely complex as your air mass depends on intake cam, exhaust cam (dynamic), cylinder volume*stroke (static), intake runner length (sometimes dynamic), humidity (dynamic), temperature (dynamic), pressure (dynamic). With all these variables you end up with a 4-6 dimensional lookup table. With a MAF you have a simple volts vs airmass lookup table, so much simpler and less sensors required.

MAF also allows for modifications without the airflow model being modified.

What is the advantage to the OEM/manafacturer by doing this?

Comment: Why do you think a MAF is simple? What does it measure?

Comment: BTW a normally aspirated engine may use one or the other or sometimes both, while a forced induction engine, either turbo or supercharged, will normally have both.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Ford went to speed density(map) on their ecoboost line, and of course, Ford Racing offers upgraded tunes while still maintaining the factory warranty.  So you can see the business advantage since it is harder for the average person to modify it without programming/tuning. As for the technical reasons, I thought this article explains it well enough - http://www.import-car.com/speed-density-engine-management-systems/2/

Comment: @Solar Mike a MAF is simple because it measures a signal that is proportional to air flow (hence air mass). This takes into account changes in volumetric efficiency (eg variable cams), humidity, altitude etc. A MAP sensors only measure pressure and temp, this means you need a volumetric efficiency map to calculate air mass. If you have variable cams this means you end up with a 4 dimensional lookup table which is complex to generate. The software behind MAP is far more complex and less forgiving to modifications.

Comment: Knowing the complexities above (I write car tuning software and the complexity is absolutely staggering, up to 50x 2D interpolation tables just to calculate the airmass in a dual VCT engine on the Fords) it makes me wonder why they do it this way. Apparently it takes 3 engineers at ford 25 weeks to calibrate an engine. If you had a MAF surely it would be cheaper, so I'm wonder what they know that I don't, as they wouldn't use something more complex without a good reason.

Comment: That links is interesting, however the only real reasons it gives is the maintenance on an AFM is higher, also that air leaks over time will cause the system to meter the wrong amount of air. Though these sort of things would surely be outside a warranty period, I wonder how the added cost of software development compares to this.

Comment: @rolls I know - I, like you studied thermofluids and power plant analysis ( density = pressure /(R *T) where R is gas constant, T is temperature) - It was for he OP. As for software cost - it is amortised over all the vehicles sold which is one reason the Bosch system gets used on several cars...

Comment: As per your edit - isn’t the inlet cam also dynamic - you stated it for the exhaust.

Comment: Yes both being dynamic in a lot of cars these days

Comment: I can imagine manufacturers equip a test car with both a MAP and MAF, and auto-learn the MAP values and corresponding MAF values into the ECU. They only have to write auto learning software once, lend the car to an employee to make test miles, and they're done; no need anymore for a MAF. Main reason probably cost reduction, as always, everywhere. Also, MAP reacts quicker than MAF in general but is indeed harder to tune yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the turbo applications I am familiar with, both a wire or film (better) type MAF is used, in conjunction with a MAP, IAT, ECT, etc.

Specifically on turbosupercharged Subarus, there's knowledge to be gained by also knowing intake pressure.

Ultimately, you are trying to reach the best AFR.  Things change a bit when supercharging, whether mechanical or turbo.

Things also change with humidity - a hot wire gets cooled more with higher humidity, which doesn't represent denser air.  Hot film type MAFs compensate for this somewhat.  But you would still like to know manifold pressure after a turbo.

I certainly agree it's more complicated:  With ROMRAIDER, I have seen there are dozens and dozens of "modifier" tables in a Subaru tune that ultimately affect injection and timing *on top* of the MAF table.  Tuning is complex with so many vectors and map layers, it's difficult to get your head around.

However, I would have to think that this added complexity serves some benefit, especially when controlling engine operation under high levels of boost.  While I know there are sophisticated speed-density systems out there, cars don't run on open loop anymore (at least not for long) and the more sensor information available, the better.

I think of it this way (it's what I tell my students):  Air "flow" tells you one thing (like the vane meters) MAF tells you a bit more, and MAF+MAP tells you almost everything.  It's just a simulation; a device to approximate.

In fact, the wire or film assumes a laminar flow in the rest of the tube, which may not be the case - especially if you put one of those "trick" $99 cold air intakes on.  The power gains you may or may not see may be due to bends in the plumbing causing the sensor area to be in a less-dense part of the total flow... so the ECU is tricked into running lean. (See? "more power" for a mere $99 . . .)

Just like an O2 sensor doesn't sense hydrocarbons, A MAF doesn't count oxygen molecules.  It's an important point.  All you really care about is how many free (not part of water) oxygen molecules are getting into the intake - not what temperature they are, the speed they are moving, how much the other gasses weigh, or what the humidity is.

If you could make a sensor that would accurately tell how many oxygen molecules are entering the intake (and maybe what temperature they are), real-time, You could eliminate a lot of other sensors and complexity.  A/F ratio would be a simple real-time division: **mL per moles O2**.

There is the empirical observation that a MAP sensor costs about $50, and a modern MAF about $500.  A speed-density based system is cheaper to produce (in quantity) after the fleet of tuners gets their job done.  But I think it hinges on the flexibility of the engine, providing sufficient power and economy while adhering to emissions rules.  Higher performance applications and supercharging may suggest more complexity is needed.

And as Bart commented, it's likely the engine is mapped and calibrated with  highly sophisticated mass-airflow instruments gathering real-time data, and then your complex 50-layer maps can be overlayed/reduced to a simple speed-density-load map with input only from the production MAP sensor.

Comment: Was unaware the cost difference was that great. It would certainly be cheaper for mass produced cars then.

Comment: Those are "replacement" costs, but the manufacturing cost is probably even a much greater difference.  A modern MAF is a very complex beast, usually with other integrated sensors (like IAT), a small dedicated computer/controller power drivers (for heating in a controlled way) and a whole bunch of firmware embedded to make the response appear "linear".  I'm certain you thermo experts can appreciate how it *isn't* linear (wire or film cooling against mass/temperature/velocity) and there's a lot more going on - beyond what I dream of understanding.

Comment: As an aside to the *complexity*, here's a great example of me flexing the wrong muscle: https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/30251/how-is-it-advantageous-for-fuel-management-to-detect-negative-mass-air-flow   There's part of this one that still haunts me.  Still, it's obvious that Bosch felt a need to sense air flow direction - something that no *MAP* I'm aware of is capable.of.

Comment: There is actually a couple of good reasons to detect direction. I just added a comment.

Comment: @rolls  I'm not sure I agree with the "big cam" part  (who cares; at idle the information has no value unless you are using it to slightly open a bypass or a throttle motor) ... BUT it exactly proves my point and ties it back to the original question:  No MAP sensor can do that, at least any that I've ever seen.

Comment: Of course it matters at idle. If the metered air is wrong the idle afr will be wrong?

Comment: @rolls  Yes, but the IAC does that, driven from O2 sensor information - not from MAF in any implementation that I'm aware of.  You won't find too many Chevy big blocks with any of this technology, and cam profile on a modern engine with a "big" cam is going to likely narrow the variable profile at idle anyway.  An engine with legitimate negative MAF flow isn't going to idle for long regardless of AFR.  Idle is controlled by throttle bypass airflow from an IAC device.  Fuel is usually at some sort of idle baseline.  Injectors are notoriously bad at accurate metering with very small duty cycles.

Comment: There's way too much lag to get the pintle off rest, as well as too much waiting for the spring to snap it closed again.  Asking for an accurate injection at a few milliseconds pulse width is physically impossible, at least for an injector that also can fuel 100 cfm at WOT.  Everything gets larger and heavier, which makes it slower.  To this day idle is still somewhat of a crapshoot, and the sore spot for tight emissions control.

Comment: I get +-2% fuel trims from a 1000cc injector. I wouldn't say it is a crapshoot, you can get pretty damn accurate fuel trims at idle with a quality injector like ID1000. Modern PCMs model the opening/closing time (deadtime) vs voltage/temp/pressure so this is all taken into account.

Comment: Injector Dynamics makes some great stuff - expensive for a reason.  In fact, they have a great write-up on their website about how their injectors are different than typical OEM, *specifically due to the carefully matched low duty cycle small injections*.